# Iterating over rows of a matrix in R, is the a better way than for loop (apply? lapply?)

Tags: r, matrix, rbind

I am new to R and while I really like the whole apply, lapply, sapply set of tools, I don't always see how to apply them.

A nutshell version of what I am doing is this.  I have a set of names in a vector.  I have a matrix, the rows of which are values (1,0) if those names should be included.

```
 mynames <- c("Bob", "Ted", "Carol", "Alice")
 myvec <- c(1,0,1,0)
 mynamemat <- matrix(mynames,1,4)
 mynamemat[,as.logical(myvec)]
```

The above works as I want.

I get Bob and Carol

So I can build up the matrix.

```
myvecmat <- matrix(myvec,1,4)
myvecmat <- rbind(myvecmat,c(1,1,0,0))
myvecmat <- rbind(myvecmat,c(0,0,1,1))
```

and then run this

```
out_list <- list(c())

for(row in 1:nrow(myvecmat)) {
    out_list[[row]] <- mynamemat[,as.logical(myvecmat[row,])]
}
print (out_list)
```

This all does what I want.  In my head it seems like I should be able to do this with one of the apply family.  But nothing I try works.

Is there a more Rish way of writing this.  Or should I just leave well enough alone.  :)

Comment: Can you provide `mynamemat` too? Also, it's not clear what role plays `mynames` in your question.

Comment: `mynamemat <- matrix(mynames, nrow=1)`?

Comment: If @Khashaa is right, you are looking for something like `t(apply(myvecmat, 1, function(x) mynamemat[, as.logical(x)]))`, though I don't see how is better than your `for` loop.

Comment: Sorry, I added it.  I didn't realize I had left that out.

Comment: Or maybe something like this `lapply(as.data.frame(t(myvecmat)), function(x) mynamemat[, as.logical(x)])`

Comment: I swear I did  `apply(myvecmat, 1, function(x) mynamemat[, as.logical(x)])` before and got a different answer.  I feel like I need more sleep.  :) Thanks everyone.  I'd be interested in seeing other solutions if people have them.

Comment: You just forgot to add `t` at the beginning probably.

Comment: Since you mention that you build your "myvecmat", if you -indeed- do not have your "myvecmat" pre-built, perhaps you could choose another approach; like: `lapply(list(c(1, 0, 1, 0), c(1, 1, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 1, 1)), function(x) mynames[as.logical(x)])`